# Como fixar um "menu horizontal" no topo da janela ao rolar a página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho um layout com uma barra de navegação horizontal na parte superior do site, ele está com `margin-top:100px`, quando rolar a página o menu deve ser fixado no topo da janela mas com `margin-top:0`.

Qual a melhor forma de realizar isso?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Você precisa controlar quando o seu menu chega ao topo da janela e nesse momento mudar a posição do menu para fixo.

Assim `$('#meuMenu').offset().top` vai dar-lhe a distancia ao topo.

Quando a distancia for <= ao valor do scroll da página, então você pode adicionar uma classe CSS que força a posição fixa:

```
.fixar {
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Assim o javascript/jquery pode ser:

```
var offset = $('#meuMenu').offset().top;
var $meuMenu = $('#meuMenu'); // guardar o elemento na memoria para melhorar performance
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    if (offset <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $meuMenu.addClass('fixar');
    } else {
        $meuMenu.removeClass('fixar');
    }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WYDhk/1/)

Answer (score 5):

### Não se é isso se você quer, segue um exemplo:

**HTML da Página:**

```
<div class="nav-container">
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SEO</a></li>
        <li><a href="">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Wordpress</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div> /*clear floating div*/
</div>
</div>
```

**Pra fazer o menu horizontal, precisa do seguinte CSS:**

```
.nav-container{ background: url('images/nav_bg.jpg') repeat-x 0 0;}
    .f-nav{ z-index: 9999; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%;} /* this make our menu fixed top */
    
.nav { height: 42px;}
    .nav ul { list-style: none; }
    .nav ul li{float: left; margin-top: 6px; padding: 6px; border-right: 1px solid #ACACAC;}
    .nav ul li:first-child{ padding-left: 0;}
    .nav ul li a { }
    .nav ul li a:hover{ text-decoration: underline;}
```

**E um pequeno código em javascript:**

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    
    var nav = $('.nav-container');
    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 136) {
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        }
    });

});
```

Fonte: http://www.sutanaryan.com/how-to-create-fixed-menu-when-scrolling-page-with-css-and-jquery/

Answer (score 3):

Você pode verificar assim:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.menu').offset().top) {

        $('.menu:not(.fixed)').addClass('fixed');

    } else $('.menu.fixed').removeClass('fixed');

});
```

Na classe CSS "fixed" você pode altera o tipo de posicionamento e remover a margem.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, com o HTML 5 e O CSS 3 não precisa fazer nenhum JQUERY ou coisa do tipo.
O Bootstrap do Twitter tem uma navbar deste estilo. basta utilizar a expressão "navbar-fixed-top" no objeto

Answer (score 0):

Pode-se conseguir somente com `CSS` atribuindo o valor `sticky` à propriedade `position`:

```
#menu {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

> A compatibilidade do recurso é bem ampla, mas parece que não fuinciona no `IE`.

Link sobre [valor sticky na propriedade position em CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)

Link para [Compatibilidade entre os navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility)

---

Exemplo:

```css
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

p {
padding: 0 10px;
text-align: justify;
}

#menu {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
margin-top: 100px;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

<div id="menu">MENU</div>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam imperdiet risus vel nulla tempus congue. Donec tincidunt, risus ac convallis tristique, nulla quam tempor turpis, et convallis ipsum felis a est. Donec iaculis at urna et egestas. Nunc purus erat, venenatis a nunc at, condimentum hendrerit lectus. Nunc aliquam purus ut massa consectetur, interdum elementum nisi aliquet. Sed rhoncus varius sapien, hendrerit tempor erat accumsan quis. Nulla tortor leo, tincidunt ac fringilla quis, malesuada non augue. Curabitur non erat cursus metus cursus hendrerit et eu tellus. Nunc mollis, nisl non porta porta, urna tellus malesuada nunc, sollicitudin semper nulla justo sed neque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed ultrices accumsan hendrerit. Aliquam luctus rutrum cursus. Maecenas ultrices nisi eu est volutpat, eu posuere felis volutpat. Nullam et leo euismod, volutpat massa eu, commodo dolor. Nunc ut blandit ex, porta consectetur purus. Nunc sit amet dolor et elit convallis convallis vitae non metus.</p>

<p>Aliquam eu libero turpis. Ut non magna at libero tincidunt lacinia et vel eros. Aenean eget nibh nec purus fringilla placerat vitae ut nisi. Praesent quis consequat urna. Vivamus porta, ante posuere finibus dignissim, lacus ante fringilla enim, vel lacinia felis nisl at elit. Suspendisse sodales sollicitudin suscipit. Etiam commodo quam nisi, quis dapibus nisl hendrerit sed. Vestibulum suscipit ut felis non vulputate.</p>

<p>Donec tempor urna quis nunc pellentesque maximus. Sed elit dui, vestibulum rutrum consequat a, viverra a leo. Vivamus eget nibh semper, suscipit eros vel, malesuada libero. Duis laoreet tempus neque, sit amet maximus odio consectetur vitae. Duis vestibulum faucibus velit eget pharetra. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer ultrices interdum ex, semper maximus turpis condimentum ut. Maecenas libero mi, bibendum vel eleifend vel, varius at neque. Praesent varius risus et diam elementum, at commodo purus fermentum. Nam luctus tempor cursus.</p>

<p>Donec rhoncus eros ipsum, ut lobortis quam tristique eu. Aliquam rhoncus, odio quis suscipit condimentum, massa ante porta dui, vel sodales sem augue quis augue. Nam maximus placerat velit in rhoncus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse eget mattis tellus. Nullam molestie tortor porttitor urna pretium, vestibulum consectetur odio molestie. Nunc ligula mauris, semper sit amet convallis ut, placerat lacinia nisi. Nunc eget lacinia dolor. Quisque placerat tellus mi, id pretium velit posuere efficitur. Nullam vitae mauris ac justo tempus lacinia id sed mauris.</p>

<p>Mauris maximus quis tortor ac semper. Proin vestibulum sed elit vel sagittis. Pellentesque sed turpis nec quam pellentesque pharetra. Suspendisse ac consectetur elit. Ut erat dolor, porttitor at tempus in, fermentum id risus. Suspendisse urna massa, blandit sed interdum nec, dapibus at nisi. Nullam eu dui ut elit dapibus venenatis eu ac magna. Nunc vehicula eget est ut sollicitudin. Suspendisse id nulla metus. Aenean suscipit luctus metus, at convallis dolor tincidunt eget.
</p>

</body>

</html>
```