# Como fazer o menu ficar fixo no topo a partir de quando acaba de passar o div anterior (que fica em porcentagem)?

Tags: javascript, menu

```css
.banner1{
    background-image: url(../images/bannertemplates.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:100%;
 height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 position:absolute;
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

.menu,
.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
    background: #000;
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner1"></div>
<ul class="menu clearfix">
  <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">xxxx</a>
            <!-- Nível 1 -->
            <!-- submenu -->
            <ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a>
    <!-- Nível 2 -->
                    <!-- submenu do submenu -->
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">xxxx</a>
      <!-- Nível 3 -->
                            <!-- submenu do submenu do submenu -->
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
                            </ul></li><!-- submenu do submenu do submenu -->
                    </ul></li><!-- submenu do submenu -->
            </ul><!-- submenu -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Eu quero que depois que o banner1 saia da tela (quando o menu chega ao topo) o menu se fixe no topo da tela

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4100/como-fixar-um-menu-horizontal-no-topo-da-janela-ao-rolar-a-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: @HigorSenna já tentei o que ta lá e não deu :/