# Como saber quando um elemento ta no topo da pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo um website no estilo one page com várias seções(sobre, contato, serviços por exemplo)

E um menu fixo, a ideia é conforme o usuário for rolando a pagina o menu fixo iria alterando os links ativos, ou seja quando estivesse na seção contato, no menu fixo o link contato ficasse "ativo"

Minha duvida é, como saber quando a seção passou pelo topo da pagina, pois assim conseguiria remover a colocar os links como ativo, obs: utilizo jquery.

Caso tenham interesse esse é o site http://mkmseguranca.com.br/

Comment: Acho que já tem varias perguntas relacionadas a isso, pesquise no StackOverflow, você irá encontrar! Uma delas aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4100/como-fixar-um-menu-horizontal-no-topo-da-janela-ao-rolar-a-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: @DouglasGarrido vou dar uma olhada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa verificar a posição da rolagem em cada ação - de rolagem. 
Então:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var divAtiva;
   $.each($("#conteudo .div-interna"), function (indice, obj) {
      if (!divAtiva || ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(obj).offset().top * 0.80 && divAtiva.top < $(obj).offset().top * 0.80))
         divAtiva = { elementId: $(obj).attr("id"), top: $(obj).offset().top };
  });
  MetodoQueSelecionaOMenu(divAtiva);
});
```

Supondo que sua estrutura seja algo semelhante a:

```
<div id="conteudo">
<div class="div-interna" id="div1">...</div>
<div class="div-interna" id="div2">...</div>
<div class="div-interna" id="div3">...</div>
</div>
```

Levei em consideração que você gostaria de selecionar a div ativa quando a rolagem atingisse 80% do seu top, ok? Diferente disso é só ir alterando o cálculo aqui: `$(obj).offset().top * 0.80` para o valor que quiser. 
(=

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        //Altura atual do scroll
        var tamScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        //Altura para disparar ação
        if(tamScroll >= 50)
        {
            //Loop para section
            $('.screen').each(function(i) {
                //verifica altura da section
                if ($(this).position().top <= tamScroll - 50) {
                    //Se satisfaz a condição, remove o link atual
                    $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                    //Adiciona classe no novo link da section atual
                    $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            //Caso não satisfaça condição principal, a página está no topo.
            $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
            $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
        }

    });
```